# Probability of picking a white ball

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

the problem:

I have a vase with a ball in it which I know to be either white or black with equal probabilities. I throw a white ball in the vase, shake, and take out a ball without  looking, which turns out to be white. Clearly the ball remaining in the vase is white or black. But what is the probability that it is white ?

Soln:
I know that

Initially, $P(W)=\frac{1}{2}$
$~and~P(B)=\frac{1}{2}$ I'm unable to proceed further...Please assist how should we go about to solve.

Any reference where I can get more such sums to solve

thanks!!

Comment: Hint : You end up with 2 balls inside the vase. One for sure is white, and the other 's colour is unknown, but you know that is white or black with the same probability.  Also notice that the probability of extracting the white ball or the "unknown-color" ball is the same

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag and tell us what have you tried as described in our policy for homework questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Imagine this equivalent variation. You have a black ball (with a tiny 'X' on it) and a white ball (with a tiny 'Y'). One is selected at random and put in the vase with a white ball labelled 'W'. You then draw 2 balls one at a time. What are the probabilities you draw YW. WY, BW and WB? Can you do it now?